# About convergence in distribution of absolute value

Tags: real-analysis, probability-theory

I am trying to verify the following for a sequence of random variables $\{X_n\}$. If $|X_n|\xrightarrow{\mathcal{D}}0$, then $X_n\xrightarrow{\mathcal{D}}0$? Here $\mathcal{D}$ stands for convergence in distribution as $n\to \infty$.

My attempt: Fix $t\in \mathbb{R}$. If $|X_n|\xrightarrow{\mathcal{D}}0$, then $P(|X_n|<t)\to 0\implies P(-t<X_n<t)\to 0$. But this does not necessarily mean $P(X_n<t)\to 0$. So I'd think the statement is false. Am I correct?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$P(|X_n|>\epsilon) \to P(0>\epsilon)=0$ for all $\epsilon >0$. This means $X_n \to 0$ in probability. Convergence in probability implies convergence in distribution.

You can also argue as follows:
$P(X_n >\epsilon)\leq P(|X_n|>\epsilon) \to 0$  $P(X_n <-\epsilon) \leq P(|X_n|>\epsilon) \to 0$, so $X_n \to 0$ indistribution.

Comment: I see, can you please elaborate on why $P(|X_n|>\epsilon)\to P(0>\epsilon)$?

Comment: @Garfield $P(|X_n|>\epsilon)=1-P(|X_n|\leq \epsilon) \to 1-P(0\leq \epsilon)=P(0>\epsilon)$

Comment: Understood, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Note that the distribution function of the random variable $0$ (which I will denote $Y_0$) is not itself $0$ : as $P(Y_0=0)=1$ we get :
$$\forall t \in \mathbb{R}, \quad F_{Y_0}(t) = \left\{ 
\begin{array}{cll} 0 &\text{if } t<0 \\ 1 &\text{if } t \geqslant 0 \end{array}\right.$$

What you then want to show is the following :

$$\textbf{if}  \left\{ \begin{array}{lll} P(|X_n|\leqslant t) \xrightarrow[n \to +\infty]{} 0 &\forall t <0\\
P(|X_n|\leqslant t) \xrightarrow[n \to +\infty]{} 1 &\forall t >0\end{array}\right. \textbf{,then} \left\{ \begin{array}{lll} P(X_n\leqslant t) \xrightarrow[n \to +\infty]{} 0 &\forall t <0\\
P(X_n\leqslant t) \xrightarrow[n \to +\infty]{} 1 &\forall t >0\end{array}\right. .$$

If you want to try this, you can stop reading here. I'll prove it in the remainder of this answer.

Assume $ \left\{ \begin{array}{lll} P(|X_n|\leqslant t) \xrightarrow[n \to +\infty]{} 0 &\forall t <0\\
P(|X_n|\leqslant t) \xrightarrow[n \to +\infty]{} 1 &\forall t >0\end{array}\right.$. Let $t>0$.

$\rhd$ let's first show that $P(X_n\leqslant -t) \xrightarrow[n \to +\infty]{} 0$. We have $P(|X_n|\leqslant t/2) \xrightarrow[n \to +\infty]{} 1$, i.e. $P(-t/2 \leqslant X_n \leqslant t/2) \xrightarrow[n \to +\infty]{} 1$; Then, as $P(-t/2 \leqslant X_n \leqslant t/2) \leqslant P(-t/2 \leqslant X_n) \leqslant 1$, we get
$$P(-t/2 \leqslant X_n) \xrightarrow[n \to +\infty]{} 1$$
therefore
$$P(X_n< -t/2) =1-P(-t/2 \leqslant X_n)\xrightarrow[n \to +\infty]{} 0.$$
As $0 \leqslant P(X_n\leqslant  -t) \leqslant P(X_n< -t/2)$, we get

$$\boxed{P(X_n\leqslant -t) \xrightarrow[n \to +\infty]{} 0.}$$

$\rhd$ let's now show that $P(X_n\leqslant t) \xrightarrow[n \to +\infty]{} 1$.
We have
$$P(X_n\leqslant t) = P(X_n< -t)+P(-t \leqslant X_n\leqslant t)$$
We already know that $P(-t \leqslant X_n\leqslant t)\xrightarrow[n \to +\infty]{} 1$ and the first part of our proof also shows that $P(X_n<-t)\xrightarrow[n \to +\infty]{} 0$. Thus

$$\boxed{P(X_n\leqslant t) \xrightarrow[n \to +\infty]{} 1.}$$

$\rhd$ Thus, we showed that if $|X_n|  \xrightarrow[n \to +\infty]{\mathcal{D}} Y_0$, then $X_n  \xrightarrow[n \to +\infty]{\mathcal{D}} Y_0$.